# Facebook SDK: User authorization and OAuth Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm working on connection of PHP and Facebook SDK for posting things on page's wall. I was searching for some tutorial explaining all things from zero, but I didn't find it, so I started working by pieces. I came to two things. First one is this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

I applied all needed permissions to login (first time I log in and after that I try to post messages offline - first by PHP POST and then by url -> developers). So there is what I added to permissions:

```
'scope' => 'offline_access, manage_pages, publish_stream, publish_actions, status_update'
```

The above error is thrown if I try to post by URL/developers centre. Second error is

```
Invalid OAuth access token signature
```

if I try to post message by PHP POST & Facebook SDK, but first I would like to solve problem number 1. What can I do?

Comment: I tried to add post through developer's explorer and it worked. The error when posting with app is still unsolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the problem. When I called Facebook SDK's API, I was putting my page ID into url like number.

Example:

```
$facebook->api('/' . 1234567890 . '/feed/', ... // this example is failed one

$facebook->api('/1234567890/feed/', ... // this example is the good one
```

That's it! :)